# UITableView - cellForRowAtIndexPath delayed rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView which its cells may vary depending on the data to be shown on each, so I have two reusable cells, the `UIPendingXOCell` and the `UIXOCell`. At some point, every `UIPendingXOCell` becomes a `UIXOCell`.

See the code below for a bit of context:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var xoItem = self.xoForIndexPath(indexPath)
        var xoItemPFObject = xoItem.pfObject

        // If it's a pending XO
        if xoItemPFObject.objectId == nil {
            var cellIdentifier = "cell-pending-xo-list"
            var cell: UIPendingXOCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UIPendingXOCell!

            ...

            return cell
        }
        else {
            var cellIdentifier = "cell-xo-list"
            var cell: UIXOCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UIXOCell!

            ...

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Example: I have a list of 5 objects, which when calling `.reloadData()` generates 1 `UIPendingXOCell` and 4 `UIXOCell` (all fine). I also have an action running on the background which changes the objects in a way that when I call `.reloadData()` again, they all become `UIXOCell` (all fine again, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called and falling into the `else` block).

My problem is that it takes about 10 seconds after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for the cell to be rendered as a `UIXOCell` rather than a `UIPendingXOCell`.

Has anyone had this problem before? If so, how should I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling reloadData on the main thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sound like you are not calling `reloadData` from main thread (UI thread). Make sure you are updating UI from main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Ridiculously simple hahah. Thanks a lot :)